# How can we update the Authorization Items in Yii RBAC tables?

Tags: yii

We have something like this, for example:

```
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;

$auth->createOperation('createPost','create a post');
$auth->createOperation('readPost','read a post');

$bizRule='return Yii::app()->user->id==$params["post"]->authID;';
$task=$auth->createTask('updateOwnPost','update a post by author himself',$bizRule);
$task->addChild('updatePost');

$role=$auth->createRole('reader');
$role->addChild('readPost');
```

Then we run, and we get the database populated. Great.

Let's say I found some issues and I need to adjust the code.

**Is there a way to programatically update the RBAC Yii tables?**

Comment: Sure, there is no reason why you can't use the code you posted inside the program in other places

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/IAuthManager#saveAuthItem-detail

Comment: @Ali MusadianPour, thanks.